# get value from array inside object

Tags: php

if i do

```
var_dump( $poll->vote_form() );
```

class method returns an array which is what i want

```
array (size=3)
  'id' => int 41
  'name' => string 'sg' (length=2)
  'options' => 
    array (size=4)
      116 => string 'dsg' (length=3)
      117 => string 'dsg' (length=3)
      118 => string 'dg' (length=2)
      119 => string 'gd' (length=2)
```

but when i do

> echo $poll->vote_form['name'];

i get error

> Undefined property: poll::$vote_form

hm what seems to be the problem?
this is the method of class poll

```
public function vote_form()
{
            ...
    $form = array('id' => $poll_id, 'name' => $poll_name, 'options' => $poll_options);
    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$data=$poll->vote_form();
echo $data['name'];
```

Comment: works perfect :) although i would like to know why is this needed hm :)

Comment: You jsut called the method of the poll calss and stores whatever it returned in a variable. SO now $data is an array and you can access it as a normal array now

Comment: Because in your code example you try to access a class property called $vote_form instead of a method vote_form(). With PHP > 5.4 you can also write $poll->vote_form()['name']; but my personal oppinion is that you should work with Marko's solution for compatibility with older PHP versions.

Comment: I understand that, but dunno why it doesnt work without added code. anyway, ty :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
echo $poll->vote_form()['name'];
```

Comment: well funny thing,  i had that code yesterday and it worked perfectly but on different computer (it could be because php version is higher?). On this computer it throws error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[',....

Comment: If this doesn't work then use @Let me see's solution :)